# DQN network cannot distinguish output ports with different actions

Tags: neural-networks, reinforcement-learning, q-learning

I am trying to implement a Deep Q-Network (DQN) with a prediction network and a target network. Both nets take the state as input and have two output ports each corresponding to a different action. Assume we have two actions $a\in \{a_1,a_2\}$.
Let $(s,a_1,r,s')$ be a transition. $\theta_{target}$ and $\theta_{predict}$ are the parameters of the two nets respectively.

Let $r + \textrm{max}_{a'} Q(s',a'|\theta_{target})$ be the target state-action value predicted using the target net, then I use $loss = \left(r + \textrm{max}_{a'} Q(s',a'|\theta_{target}) - Q(s,a_1|\theta_{predict})\right)^2$ to do a gradient descent step on $\theta_{predict}$.

I have one question. The above loss only considered the chosen action $a_1$ and we do not have a target value for the other acton $a_2$, i.e., $Q(s,a_2|\theta_{predict})$. I saw most literature ignores this and assumes the loss for $a_2$ is just zero. However, this means the prediction net only learns one output port $(s,a_1)$ but not the other. How to let it learn both the outputs $(s,a_1)$ and $(s,a_2)$ at the same time given the transition $(s,a_1,r,s')$?